# inserting array into query then looping through results into new query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

basically this is on the end of a dynamic form where the user can add multiple users of however many they want to a group, so i storte all the inputs in an array user[].

I want to query the array values and gain the userid for each then run another query with the user ids, inserting the userids into another table.

I am a beginner so I am getting lost in this. I looked at trying to use a for each method but couldnt get that working so now im trying a while.

here is my code ive been playing around with, i imagine its completely wrong :(

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users_tb WHERE student_number IN('.implode(',', $array).')';
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$result=mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO group_assocation_tb (group_id, user_id) VALUES('$group','$row['user_id']')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_close();
}
```

please help? :D

regards

Comment: pulled out mysql_close(); from the loop and spelt the table name right and works.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the problem. But you should really think about using [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442396/inserting-array-into-query-then-looping-through-results-into-new-query/5442428#5442428), because your approach is highly ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use [INSERT SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-select.html):

```
INSERT INTO group_association (group_id, user_id)
  SELECT ' . $group_id . ', user_id
  FROM users_tb WHERE student_number IN('.implode(',', $array).')
```

Comment: why would I be selecting the group id from users_tb when there isnt a group id in that table? i want to grab the userids of which match the student numbers inputted into the previous form ( in the array), then store those userids with the groupid into a completely separate table.

Comment: You don't select the group id from users_tb. When parsing this, php generates the following string:

    **INSERT INTO group_association (group_id, user_id)
      SELECT 12, user_id
      FROM users_tb WHERE student_number IN(3,5,7)**

assuming group_id = 12 and the array has the values 3,5 and 7. this ensures that the insert query gets as many values as needed to create each row

Answer (score 0):

You have some extra quotes in the INSERT query, it should look like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO group_assocation_tb (group_id, user_id) ".
       "VALUES('$group','$row[user_id]')";
```

Other than that, it looks like it should work if `$group` is a group id.

Comment: think it would also help if i spelt the table name right :D thanks

Comment: i now get this error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1" i think its happening on that query.

Comment: no worries, fiddled around with the code and it works. thanks anyway!